# Obj-C Setters returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I am making a simple app and this piece of code has been giving me issues.
Here is my property.
In ConverisonCalculator.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *startingUnit;
```

In Viewcontroller.m I am using this code and everytime I NSLog it I am getting (null)

```
_calculator.startingUnit = @"FPS";
```

Also here is my lazy instantiation of the object.

```
- (ConversionCalculator *)calculator{
if (!_calculator) _calculator = [[ConversionCalculator alloc]init];
return _calculator; }
```

I hope this is enough for you to answer my question. I am not override the default setter either.

Here is my logging.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_calculator startingUnit]);
```

Comment: You don't describe which part of the code has unexpected results.

Comment: Show us the NSLog and surrounding context.

Comment: show your logging method?

Comment: how the calculator object as property defined?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [_calculator startingUnit]); try this because your object is string not a flot

Comment: Sorry I had been trying a log on another property that was a float, and copied the wrong call, updated.

Comment: try changing the property identifier to `copy` and see. If it works. Then check the context where u are esetting the value. it is getting destroyed or maybe u are setting it null from where else ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_calculator.startingUnit = @"FPS";
```

This is *not* using your property. This is direct access to the instance variable, so your lazy loading code is never called.

If you define properties, **always** access them through the property:

```
self.calculator.startingUnit = @"FPS";
```

Otherwise, you might as well be using instance variables. The only exception is inside the accessor methods themselves, or in init or dealloc methods (in some cases).